# Is this supposed to look different?

Tags: support, design

[image: New bar]

Is this supposed to be here? It doesn't fit with the colour scheme of Ask Different, and it appeared recently, without warning or explanation (that I could find).

Comment: Not sure if the bug tag is 100% fitting, but it seemed to be the best of the necessary tags.

Comment: This is intentional and temporary.

Comment: This should be permanent. I really like the dash of colors.

Comment: For a split–second I actually thought SE was acquired by Google. — But after reading the news I see the intended symbolism. *Kudos!* for the design.

Comment: I think the colors look nice. It reminds me of Apple's old logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the colors of the original Apple Logo:

[image: Apple Logo]

It appeared with the update to the site design that added the "Steve Jobs passed away on October 5th, 2011. Rest in peace." line to the top.

Comment: I did recognize the colours, but I wanted to be sure that it was intentional. The colour change actually happened afterwards, about 1 hour ago I was on here, had a normal menu bar, but the Steve Jobs update was there.

Comment: @Mahnax yeah, it took a little while to make and deploy the design change